# Swiss German Learning

Tags: resource-request, german, germanic-languages

Can anyone suggest any resources for learning Swiss German?

Since Swiss German is not an official language but a dialect it is very hard to find any resources.

Ideally targetd for beginners with no knowledge of High German.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you please add whether this is for people who already know Standard German? This makes a huge difference with regard to available resources.

Comment: I edited my post, assume that the learner does not have a knowledge of Standard German.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google search brings up quite a few results. Pimsleur, the language learning program, has a [Swiss German course available for $42 USD](http://www.pimsleur.com/learn-swiss-german), which includes ten thirty-minute mp3 lessons that will give you a basic foundation in the language. The website [Swiss German Online](http://www.swiss-german-online.com/lessons.html) has a list of commonly used phrases in Swiss German, as well other language basics.

[This is a Memrise course](https://www.memrise.com/course/63500/swiss-german-1-schwiizertuutsch-schwyzerdutsch/) that claims to teach you basic vocabulary, grammar, greetings, and numbers as an introduction to the dialect. Finally, [this website](http://www.newlyswissed.com/swiss-german-language-apps/) has a list of several apps targeted towards Swiss German speakers or learners, including dictionaries as well as other tools.

This [FluentU page](http://www.fluentu.com/german/blog/learn-swiss-german/) has a list of helpful tips on your journey towards fluency in the language. [This last resource](http://www.englishforum.ch/language-corner/17908-resources-learning-swiss-german-all-dialects.html) is essentially a megathread of all sorts of language learning resources for Swiss German: it includes audio materials, movies to watch (with Swiss German dialogue), classes to take, books to read, and various other dictionaries to use.

As a bonus, I'm including this [Duolingo forum page](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/4802531) that might prove of use to you. Before you start learning Swiss German specifically, I'd just like to highlight that on the Duolingo page, a native speaker of Swiss German (living in Switzerland) says this:

> I live in Switzerland. Most foreigners here learn High German instead of Swiss German. (If you look at the language school offerings here you will see they overwhelmingly teach High German, and barely teach Swiss German.) If someone says something to you in Swiss German you can reply in High German and they will understand you and usually politely switch over to High German. The Swiss tend to be very polite. Frankly, I live here, and I don't hear that much Swiss German other than at the grocery store and that is pretty minimal! Unless you are incredibly interested, or want to specifically speak Swiss German, it is a better use of your time to focus on Hochdeutsch (High or Standard German). Just my two cents.